# Do need to worry about PCI compliance if I use Stripe or Authorize.net with WooCommerce? And what do I have to do?

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, pci-compliance, authorize.net-cim

I'd like to set up a Wordpress site and use [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/). In terms of payment processors, I'd like to use either [Authorize.net CIM](http://www.woothemes.com/products/authorize-net-cim/) or [Stripe](http://www.woothemes.com/products/stripe/). At the top of each of those pages, it says that an SSL certificate is required, so based on that fact and [the PCI-DSS Compliance article on the WooCommerce site](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/pci-dss-compliance-and-woocommerce/), I assumed that **PCI Compliance would be necessary.** Is that correct?

**If I do need to worry about PCI Compliance**, what does that mean I need to do? I'm familar with the 12 requirements, I just don't understand the practical implications for *me*.

Specifically, I understand that many of the PCI requirements are covered by the hosting provider. Others PCI requirements are covered by the coding. Both of those things I don't have to really worry about, once it's set up. One thing I know *I'll* need to do, though, is enable SSL on the site. *Is there anything else I am responsible to do*, though? For example, annually get my site scanned for PCI Compliance? Manage my store in a particular way?

Any info is more than welcome! Things are a bit vague for me regarding this and PCI Compliance.

Comment: Which Authorize.Net API will you be using? This will determine what portion of PCI compliance you need to be aware of.

Comment: I'd be using the CIM one.

Comment: Hosted CIM? or will the user be filling out the info on your site?

Comment: I'd be using this pluging: http://www.woothemes.com/products/authorize-net-cim/, so I believe they'd be filling out the info on my site?

Comment: You will have *a lot* of PCI compliance issues that you will be responsible for. This includes server security including the network it is on, coding and storage concerns, etc. For starters, shared hosting is out of the question.

Comment: Would the same be true of Stripe?

Comment: Does that take the user off of your site to complete the payment process?

Comment: Well, I think customers initially fill out the credit card info on my site, but then it sends it directly to Stripe. Stripe's help section makes it seem as if PCI concerns would be minimal: https://support.stripe.com/questions/do-i-need-to-be-pci-compliant-what-do-i-have-to-do

Comment: It will definitely reduce the amount of compliance you have to be concerned about.

Answer (score 4):

This is [Stripe's response on unofficial site](https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-Stripe-payment-method-PCI-compliant/answer/Cristina-Cordova?ch=10&share=b5ec807f&srid=h7bI)

**Cristina Cordova, works at Stripe**
Answered Aug 22, 2013
  *

> **I work at Stripe.** As others have mentioned, anyone accepting credit
>   card payments must be PCI compliant. With many other service providers
>   in the online payments space, becoming PCI compliant is a very
>   complicated process requiring businesses to fill out lots of paperwork
>   and work with several expensive third parties.  **With Stripe, it's
>   easy:**
>
> 1.Serve your payment page over SSL, i.e., the page's web address
>   should begin with "https", not "http".
>
> 2.Use Stripe.js as the only means
>   by which you accept payment information and transmit it directly to
>   Stripe's servers.
>
> **By taking these steps, you completely avoid handling
>   sensitive card data, and keep your systems out of PCI scope.** Using SSL
>   ensures that your pages are secure. Stripe.js makes it easy to collect
>   credit card (and other similarly sensitive) details without having the
>   information touch your server. **Those details are sent directly to
>   Stripe, which is a PCI Level 1 Service Provider.**  Assuming you've
>   taken the steps above, Stripe can provide you with a completed Self
>   Assessment Questionnaire, which details the means by which you're
>   handling credit card data.

Stripe's official guidance on PCI compliance:
https://stripe.com/docs/security